# Visual Select Range of Lines and Sort IP Adresses

Tags: visual-mode

I have a mapleader macro to sort IP addresses and delete leading 0 in IP addresses

```
let mapleader='ip'
map <leader>ips :%s/0\+\([0-9a-f]\)/\1/ | %sort n /.*\./ | %sort n /\.\d\+\./ | %sort n /\./ | %sort n u
```

This works but it always selects the whole text.

I am searching for a solution where I can visually select with `V` lines and then call a map that only this lines get sorted.

How can I do this?

Comment: Won't `s/0\+\([0-9a-f]\)/\1/` turn `102` into `12`?

Answer (score 2):

A simple version just reuses the range provided in visual mode:

```
xnoremap <leader>ips :s/0\+\([0-9a-f]\)/\1/ | *sort n /.*\./ | *sort n /\.\d\+\./ | *sort n /\./ | *sort n u
```

- `x` for visual but not select mode
- `noremap` for a non-recursive mapping
- `*` for the equivalent range as `'<,'>`, which is a pain to type. It gets filled in automatically when you press `:` in visual mode though.

Comment: Thanks but it still does not work (It seems I miss something?)
I made in .vimrc let mapleader=',' xnoremap \<leader\>ip :s/0\+\([0-9a-f]\)/\1/ \<bar\> *sort n /.*\./ \<bar\> *sort n /\.\d\+\./ \<bar\> *sort n /\./ \<bar\> *sort n u\<CR\> If I select the Lines with V and then press : I got in the status line
:'<,'> and I complete it with map leader "," and ip :'<,'>,ip
Return At once an error occurs
E481: No range allowed What is my error?

Comment: @VIM_User assuming this was meant to be a comment on this post, I've converted it. If you're the OP, we can merge the accounts… the previous commenter was correct. Type `,ip` from visual mode. The mapping does the `:` for you.